ggplot geom_sf legend categories missing when no data in category despite drop = F
I'm trying to display proportions to a map - I had previously used this code at a state level but now that I've gone down to an SA4 level the legend is playing up.
I've read several other posts where the suggestion has been to add drop = FALSE but my code already has this, so is there something else I'm missing?
My code is in a function because I reproduce many different iterations of this map and parse the values through x
aus_shp<- read_sf("map files/SA4_2021_AUST_GDA2020.shp")
exclude_list <- c('Other Territories')
aus_shp$x <- rep(0,1)

my_colours<- c("#FFFFFF","#D3D3D3","#00B050", "#92D050", "#FFFFB2", "#FED976", "#FEB24C", "#FD8D3C", "#F03B20", "#BD0026")

scale_theme<- function(...){
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colours,
    limits = levels(aus_shp$x),
    labels = c("not availailable","<30 reports", "<1%", "1-<5%", "5-<10%", "10-<15%", "15-<20%", "20-<25%", "25-50%", ">50%"),
    name = "% R",
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list (color = NA), reverse = TRUE),
    drop = F)}

state_map<- function(...){
  aus_shp$x <- cut(x,
                   breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 0.1, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100),
                   right = FALSE)
  ggplot(data = aus_shp) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = x))+
    theme_void()+
    scale_theme()}

x<- runif(108, min = 5, max = 49) 

state_map()

For the dummy x variable I've generated random data with limits that can replicate the error I come across with my actual data. Please note that the <30 category is coded as 0.0 and the "not available" is coded as 0.1 but doesn't show in this random example.
You see in this map the categories for <5 and >49 are not showing...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Try geom_sf(aes(fill = x), show.legend = TRUE). This is now required due to a recent change in ggplot2 >= 3.5.0. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78305635/ggplot-legend-showing-blank-fill-for-missing-factor-level/78306354#78306354

@stefan yet again you come to my rescue!!!!
