scale_fill_manual - color of missing levels are not shown in legend
scale_fill_manual - missing levels are not colored in legend
Running the examples at https://tidyverse.github.io/ggplot2-docs/reference/scale_manual.html I am wondering if the behaviour of scale_fill_manual has changed recently. The color is now missing for cyl = 10, i.e. for the last figure shown in the example.
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=nb-NO.UTF-8  LC_CTYPE=nb-NO.UTF-8    LC_MONETARY=nb-NO.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C            LC_TIME=nb-NO.UTF-8
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.9.2    forcats_1.0.0      stringr_1.5.1      purrr_1.0.2        readr_2.1.5        tidyr_1.3.1        tibble_3.2.1
[8] tidyverse_2.0.0    RColorBrewer_1.1-3 dplyr_1.1.4        ggplot2_3.5.0
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] nlme_3.1-162       matrixStats_0.63.0 xts_0.13.0         gsw_1.1-1          threejs_0.3.3      rstan_2.32.6       tools_4.2.3
[8] utf8_1.2.4         rgdal_1.5-31       R6_2.5.1           DT_0.33            colorspace_2.1-0   raster_3.6-26      withr_3.0.0
[15] sp_1.4-7           tidyselect_1.2.1   gridExtra_2.3      curl_5.2.1         compiler_4.2.3     cli_3.6.2          shinyjs_2.1.0
[22] labeling_0.4.3     colourpicker_1.3.0 scales_1.3.0       dygraphs_1.1.1.6   QuickJSR_1.1.3     digest_0.6.35      StanHeaders_2.32.6
[29] minqa_1.2.5        oce_1.8-2          rstanarm_2.21.4    base64enc_0.1-3    pkgconfig_2.0.3    htmltools_0.5.8.1  lme4_1.1-32
[36] fastmap_1.1.1      htmlwidgets_1.6.4  rlang_1.1.3        rstudioapi_0.16.0  shiny_1.8.1.1      farver_2.1.1       generics_0.1.3
[43] zoo_1.8-11         jsonlite_1.8.8     crosstalk_1.2.1    gtools_3.9.4       zip_2.3.1          inline_0.3.19      magrittr_2.0.3
[50] loo_2.7.0          bayesplot_1.11.1   Matrix_1.5-3       Rcpp_1.0.12        munsell_0.5.1      fansi_1.0.6        lifecycle_1.0.4
[57] terra_1.7-71       stringi_1.8.3      MASS_7.3-58.2      pkgbuild_1.4.4     plyr_1.8.8         grid_4.2.3         parallel_4.2.3
[64] promises_1.2.0.1   miniUI_0.1.1.1     lattice_0.20-45    splines_4.2.3      hms_1.1.3          pillar_1.9.0       igraph_1.4.2
[71] boot_1.3-30        markdown_1.12      shinystan_2.6.0    reshape2_1.4.4     codetools_0.2-20   stats4_4.2.3       rstantools_2.4.0
[78] glue_1.7.0         V8_4.4.2           RcppParallel_5.1.7 tzdb_0.4.0         vctrs_0.6.5        nloptr_2.0.3       httpuv_1.6.9
[85] gtable_0.3.5       openxlsx_4.2.5.2   mime_0.12          xtable_1.8-4       later_1.3.0        survival_3.5-3     shinythemes_1.2.0
[92] timechange_0.2.0

Yup. There was a change in the guide system which now requires to add show.legend=TRUE in the geom (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78305635/ggplot-legend-showing-blank-fill-for-missing-factor-level/78306354#78306354), i.e. you have to use geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)), show.legend = TRUE) for the example. Actually the ggplot2 docs show the example with the missing symbol :D (see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html).
